# Hashtag RegExp in Javascript breaks links with anchors and HTML entities

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, hashtag

I'm trying to parse hashtags in Javascript (node.js). I have some requirements for these hashtags: they can be written using cyrillic symbols, should not break HTML entities like `&#039;` and links (`https://example.com/hacking#stage3`).

I've read many examples on this site, but none worked for me: if one feature appears then other breaks. Now I'm stuck with URL filtering: negative lookahead doesn't work as I wish and links are still broken. This is my current regex:

```
(?!#[0-9])#([^#][a-zA-Z\d\u0400-\u04ff]+)
```

I'm testing it here: https://regex101.com/r/gN9fT3/4. It works partially: link is broken. How to fix it? What regex or JS feature I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a non-word boundary `\B`:

```
\B#([a-zA-Z\u0400-\u04ff][a-zA-Z\d\u0400-\u04ff]*)
```

An other possible way consists to capture all that you want to avoid in a capture group placed before your target, example:

```
(pattern for links)|#([a-zA-Z\u0400-\u04ff][a-zA-Z\d\u0400-\u04ff]*)
```

So with this pattern, if the group 1 exists, the replacement is `$1`, if it doesn't, use the replacement you want. *(don't forget that now the hashtag is the capture group 2)*

Answer (score -1):

Use TNNSUKA.js lib, there have more functions to your problem. I looked it lib on lab.nyan.pw/sosi, you can downland on this page.